# In WinRT, is it possible to decrypt text encrypted with .NET RijndaelManaged algorithm?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, windows-runtime

The WinRT library (C# Windows 8 Application development) does not have the [RijndaelManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class as .NET has. But it does have a lot of [AES-algorithms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.openalgorithm%28v=win.10%29.aspx), which as far as I understand is [a subse](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2006/10/09/the-differences-between-rijndael-and-aes.aspx)t of the Rijndael algorithm. Can I decrypt text encrypted in .NET with the RijndaelManaged-class, where I've used a 128 bit IV and 256 bit key?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is certainly possible. It's a standardized algorithm, and it seems to me that at least the CBC + PKCS7Padding is present in both. Of course, this does not work when the *block* size of Rijndael is choosen to be 256 bit long instead of the standardized 128 bits.